# How to hit React hook breakpoints in VS Code debugger?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js

In short, my VSCode debugger is able to hit all breakpoints except for the ones within React hooks (useEffect, setState) within my nextjs app.

For example, consider the following React function component:

```
export default function example() {
  console.log("breakpoint 1");
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("breakpoint 2");
  });
  return (<div></div>);
}
```

Assuming I add a breakpoint at both console.log statements, the VS Code debugger will pause at `breakpoint 1` but will not pause at `breakpoint 2` even though console output shows that both lines are run.

Comment: Also having this issue...